# Why is my TeXStudio inserting ramdom ascii symbols in the code?

Tags: symbols, texstudio

and thanks for answering, in advance.

I am using TeXstudio 2.12.4 with Qt 5.6.2. (whatever it means. Sorry I'm new to all this and I barely know anything).

The thing is that, when I am typing code, the program inserts random ascii symbols in the middle of the code. I noticed that this happens when using "\" before commands or characters. For example, when I am writing math formulas, if I want to write "8\pi", it always gives error because, for some reason, there appeared "8\♦pi" or "8\•pi" or whatever. It is very frustrating because I don't realize it all the times and it keeps giving errors over and over again.

I've been dealing with this for weeks, but it is starting to get really annoying. So, why does the \ sometimes add those symbols?

I think the symbol is related to the "time" (in nanoseconds?) I keep the key AltGr pressed. It doesn't always happen , but it does too many times. Also, this is the only program where I see this. What is happening?

Thank you so much for your help.

Comment: Are you sure you are not hitting any other key on your keyboard while holding the `Alt Gr` key? On my device (Ubuntu laptop) this happens from time to time while typing. (In my case, I get an `·` when accidentally hitting the comma key while the `Alt Gr` key is pressed for example.)

Comment: Yes, 100% sure. I don't type to well, okay, but my keyboard is big enough and I have been checking it out many times. What's more, this doesn't happen when I type the same in a notepad, for example.

Comment: It sounds more like a case for the bug tracker of  texstudio https://sourceforge.net/p/texstudio/bugs/. And you should mentioned your OS and the keyboard layout your are using.

Comment: In which encoding is the tex file saved?

Comment: @DavidCarlisle this is not about output, it's about the input: some times you try to type `\cmd` you get `\<randomsym>cmd`.

Comment: Some times this happen for me when typing a comment here in the site. So it can be related to the  OS or the keyboard as @UlrikeFischer already noticed.

Comment: Strange enough, I came here because my TeXstudio does the same. Sadly, this affects so few people that it might never be resolved :-(

Comment: @Mitja The problem is not that too few people are affected, but that we try to help and not get any feedback to the queries asked. Knowing what the OS and keyboard layout is could maybe help.

Comment: Sorry, I removed my malformatted comment, here it is again: @samcarter `TeXstudio 2.12.4 (hg 6476:3e5c3afa4719) Nutze Qt-Version 5.6.2, kompiliert mit Qt 5.6.2 R`. This happens on Windows 8.1 using a standard german keyboard. I can't really think on how this could be reproducible. It seems to happen randomly, but only after typing a `\ ` character. Seems to only occur when typing "normally", it is not triggered by testing with patterns like `\\\\\\\\...` or `\a \a \a \a ....`

Comment: @Mitja Thanks! I have two theories to test: 1) maybe some interaction with the auto-complete. Can you please go to texstudio preferences, enable "show advances options" and switch off all auto-completion features (in the tab "completion")? Does the problem still occur? 2) to test if the combination of keys causes the problem, it would be interesting this problems also occurs if the \ is directly accessible. You could test this if you'd switch to e.g. us layout.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is essentially a bug report.

Comment: Okay, you can do what you want, you're too many... BUT, could you at least tell me what to do (or where to post it or whatever) **clearly**? I'm here because I wanted to solve this problem, and it seems there are more people like me.

Comment: @FGSUZ You might want to keep track of the discussion on [Github](https://github.com/texstudio-org/texstudio/issues/164#issue-327696551); sounds like a similar problem.